# img tag defaultly loading while uploading image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying upload image that the time img tag defaultly loading I don't  know why it is loading I am not put any img tag 
Here is my HTML code

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="file"  ng-click="clear()" 
      onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload(event)" accept="image/png, image/jpeg,image/jpg" style="display: block;"  />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" ng-click="click()">Upload</button>
  </div>
```

After Uploading the image result will come like this

```html
 <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="file"  ng-click="clear()" 
      onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload(event)" accept="image/png, image/jpeg,image/jpg" style="display: block;"  />
<img src = "base64 Image DATA " >
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" ng-click="click()">Upload</button>
  </div>
```

JS

````js
    $scope.setImage = function (image) {
        $scope.display = $scope.images[image];
    }

    $scope.upload = function (obj) {
        var elem = obj.target || obj.srcElement;
            $scope.file = elem.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();

            $scope.fileName =   $scope.file.name;             
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $scope.display = e.target.result;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL($scope.file);
    }   
    $scope.afterClick = false;
    $scope.loadingImages = true;
    $scope.errors = true;
    $scope.click = function() {
    $scope.loadingImages = false;
    Upload.upload(
    {
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/image/getDeepLearningPredections',
        file : $scope.file,
        data : {
                fileName : $scope.fileName,
                }
            }).then(function(response) {

            }

    ```
In the Above added JS code 
Please let me know what is the problem
````

Comment: give your js code also! i think it is because of js code

Comment: added js code Please let me know problem